# In JavaFx, how to remove a specific node from a gridpane with the coordinate of it?

Tags: java, javafx

If I know the specific coordinate of the node I am trying to remove, let's say "col:3, row: 4", how can I remove the node in column 3 and row 4? 
Is there a built-in method I can use in Java?

Comment: What do you mean by removing? What should the other nodes do?

Comment: I literally mean removing the node from the gridPane. Let' say I wanna remove an imageview from a gridPane. And other nodes don't do anything.

Comment: Try to remove a cell in Excel, i would ask you what the other cells should do: the below ones move upward, the right ones move left, or remove the whole column or row...

Comment: Or you just want to hive the contents? Try something like `imageView.setVisible(false)`

Comment: First of all, I am doing on Excel, I am doing it on JavaFx. Second, I want to remove an element or a node from gridPane, I want it to be gone. For example, my gridpane has cells with different label, if I click on specific cell, I want the label on that cell to be gone. That's what I mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a node at (row,col) in a JavaFX GridPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154996/replace-a-node-at-row-col-in-a-javafx-gridpane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove node (child) from layout (GridPane)

```
public Node removeNodeByRowColumnIndex(final int row,final int column,GridPane gridPane) {

ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();
for(Node node : childrens) {
    if(node instanceof ImageView && gridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && gridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
        ImageView imageView=ImageView(node); // use what you want to remove
        gridPane.getChildren().remove(imageView);
        break;
    }
  } 
   }
```

Comment: How does it answer the question "I am trying to remove, let's say col:3, row: 4" ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous,you don't need coordinates to remove nodes ,just if you have Fx id of node just write gridepane.getChildren().remove(fx_id_node)

Comment: It is not my question. I don't think it is ambiguous.

Comment: This was giving me the weirdest NPE I've ever seen and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in methods to remove child nodes from GridPane using row-column coordinate. Insteed you should work with index on the getChildren() method return list.

So you should most probably put in place a strategy how to you add nodes to GridPane, because the nodes are simply added to the end of the list and not reordered accordly row or colum indexes.

In addition remember to considere that all removed node from the list decrements the index of all remaining nodes above. This could be as well source of run-time errors.

It could be worthfully to call as well the static method clearConstraints() to remove all constraints you put in place explicitly or implicitly.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best, and the shortest way is:

```
gridPane.getChildren().removeIf( node -> GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row);
```

`removeIf` method removes all elements from the gridPane that satisfy the specified condition, given as method.

Answer (score 0):

If you get null pointer exceptions from the above solution, set the parent if of the (col, row) node you want to remove and you can do like so

```
boolean removeFromPane(String id) {
    for (final Node node : this.gridPane.getChildren()) {
        if (node != null 
              && node.getId() != null
              && node.getId().equals(this.selectedTask.toString())) {
            return this.gridPane.getChildren().remove(node);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```